# How to setup github on your local using git?

Tags: git, github, git-clone

I have my credential setup for git but when i try to clone private repository from github its throwing below error , Any idea what could be the reason of failing and how i can resolve this issue.

error

```
$ git clone https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js.git -b v0.16.2
Cloning into 'bpmn-js'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Timed out
```

Comment: did you install git?

Comment: yes git is installed

Comment: Are you behind a proxy, a firewall?

Comment: use the `git:` url, not the `https` url.

Comment: is `2FA` enabled?

Comment: did you read https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/ ?

Comment: I am fairly new two these terms 2FA etc, How can i check if i am behind proxy ?

Comment: @njzk2 The `git:` scheme is for anonymous use and probably firewalled (or in this case not whitelisted). Did you mean `git@`, the ssh connection?

Comment: @Schwern yes, that's what I meant. Too late to edit my comment, though.

Answer (score 0):

That machine you're on probably has a proxy or firewall which is preventing access to Github, or it has a bad internet connection in general.

Git is making a normal HTTPS connection. Debug it like one.

- Try https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js.git/ in a web browser.
- If that doesn't work, try https://google.com to see if all HTTPS is blocked.

Be sure to do it on the same machine as you're running git commands.

In either case, you'll probably want to talk to your network administrator.

Comment: I was able to access https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js.git/ from browser, let me talk to me network administrator